# apache2 не видит .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, apache, apache2

Проблема распрастраненая, сначало облазил кучу мануалов и пробывал разные варианты, в итоге не зашло. Вот теперь пишу.
Только вникаю в linux. поставил апач2 туда засунул mod_rewrite, 
создал виртуальный хост ( закинул туда проектик на yii2 с openservera )

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

в настройках апача  , а именно тут /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
прописано следующее :  `AccessFileName .htaccess`

виртуальный хост загружается - с этим проблем нет , а вот файл .htaccess не видит в упор. Отмечу - что в синтаксисе самого проекта ошибок нет, т.к взят рабочий проект с win OpenServer.

и дополнительный вопрос apache и apache2 , различие в версиях?

подскажите что с этим делать?

возможно я не установил какие либо моды?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблему решил, может у когото будет такая же.
в этих мануалах написано с ошибкой.
оствлю это тут.

для того что бы было видно файл `.htaccess`, необходимо помимо настроек виртуального хоста прописать в конфиге апача 
`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

и вот это:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: [Там правильный ответ с форматированием](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)

Comment: у меня заработало, только путь ```/``` стоит вместо ```/var/www```

Answer (score 0):

Часто модуль rewrite выключен (в ubuntu и debian по умолчанию так). Включить a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 0):

```
AllowOverride All
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
В секции, отвечающей за директорию достаточно

(проверил на httpd+CentOS)